# Why is blood pressure different in different parts of our blood vessels?

Tags: hematology

Why does it change throughout our circulatory system ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. You could visit the [tour-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) for basic informations, the [help-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more detailed informations about what [could be asked](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [could not be](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For formatting tasks in command prompt, visit [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) help sub-page. Thanks

Comment: Blood pressure changes throughout the circulatory system because the blood vessels (both veins and arteries) have **different radius** throughout the body. Also, the further you go from the heart, less pressure it will have. This is physics. Fluid Mechanics, specifically. Check out the Navier-Stokes for more insight on the subject. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics#Fluid_dynamics https://www.boundless.com/biology/textbooks/boundless-biology-textbook/the-circulatory-system-40/blood-flow-and-blood-pressure-regulation-227/blood-pressure-855-12100/